# Ubuntu black screen after grub choosing "Ubuntu" on boot

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04

My machine is on Ubuntu 22.04. Recently after one update, it shows a completely black screen after the grub selection. If I choose the advanced Ubuntu option on grub, and choose one recovery mode, and then choose resume to boot, it can boot just fine. There has been no such problem before. Anyone has any idea?